# Ubuntu Chromium saves passwords but does not recall them? These passwords are accessible on my phone

Tags: password, chromium

On my desktop, I'm running Chromium Version 103.0.5060.53 (Official Build) snap (64-bit) on top of Ubuntu 21.10 (EDIT as suggested by @guiverc: I upgraded to 22.04 to try to solve the problem.  It changed nothing.)  I also have an Android phone which runs Chrome (not Chromium).  Both devices are logged into the same Google account.

Several months ago, Chromium on my desktop machine stopped filling in user name/password fields which I know that I had saved.  I can re-enter these user names and passwords, and Chromium will still prompt me to save them.  I can see these passwords are stored under my account at https://passwords.google.com/.  But on a return visit to a web site, auto-filling no longer occurs.

I rarely try to use my phone to log in to password-secured sites, but I just did so right now.  A site I have never visited before using my phone let me straight through, auto-filling my user name and password.

I suspect that Chromium on my desktop is either corrupted, or that there is a setting I need to change.

I would be grateful for your advice, thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI:   Don't forget [Ubuntu 21.10 is in it's last days of *support*](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/) so plan your time to *release-upgrade* whilst you have *days* left, and not *hours*.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to upgrade Ubuntu, @guiverc.  I am now running 22.04.  Unfortunately, the upgrade did not change my Chromium version, it is still 103.0.5060.53.  And my passwords are still not auto-filling.

Comment: FYI:  As *snap* packages are the same regardless of your re: OS version: the issues experienced in one release should not vary with another with snap packages (one benefit of Ubuntu Core releases is when you upgrade from one release to another; no user apps change as all apps are all snaps). If you're now running 22.04; you should amend your question.  FYI:  I've had issues before where my profile for `chromium` has lost prior saved data, but it's due to corruption, and I've corrected via copying the old data to the new config; but that's all local machine only & unrelated to google/phone

Comment: Hey I had the same issue - I just ended up uninstalling chromium and then installing it via snap again: `sudo apt purge chromium-browser && sudo snap remove chromium && rm -rf ~/snap/chromium && sudo snap install chromium`. I exported my bookmarks before doing this and re-imported them after. Not really a good solution if you have a lot of other settings but this seemed to fix the chromium installation for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question, but I must thank @guiverc and @Victor Parmar for getting me to think about snap packages versus system packages (which I believe are installed with elevated privileges and for multiple users).

I've used Synaptic Package Manager for over a decade.  I tried Ubuntu Software Center a few times and kept concluding that it wasn't mature yet.  Well, it eventually matured, and when I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10, I decided to install Chromium ***as a snap***.

I think that was the mistake.  I think this created a parallel user profile rather than reusing my old one.

I uninstalled the Chromium snap and I reinstalled it the old-fashioned way, as a system package, using Synaptic.  This restored all my password access!